# Bijection which preserves convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does there exist a bijection $f: \mathbf{N} \to \mathbf{N}$ such that
$$
\forall A \subseteq \mathbf{N}, \quad 
\sum_{n \in A}\frac{1}{n}<\infty \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{n \in A}\frac{1}{\sqrt{f(n)}}<\infty\,\,?
$$

Comment: Well $\implies$ is easy since you can just define $f(n)=n$, but as for the $\impliedby$ case, not so easy.

Comment: I believe the answer is no. But I don't have a proof, just a lack of examples.

Comment: Very good question by the way ! (+1) :-)

Comment: @ Ty Jensen don't you mean the other way round?

Comment: Does this answer the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2429389/is-there-a-bijection-of-the-natural-numbers-which-swaps-frac1n-summable-s?rq=1

Comment: @AdamRubinson Surely yes! Thank you Adam. Please vote to close this question

Comment: Thank you for the fun question Paolo!

Comment: @TyJensen You are welcome, I am just afraid it was a duplicate, I didn't know it

Comment: I'm not sure if "voting to close" it the same as "flagging as duplicate", but I don't know how to do the former, so I've done the latter.

Comment: Paolo at least you don't have to give away 500 reputation to get an answer like the original questioner did! To be fair, that answer is probably worth 500 rep anyway.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Ahaha this should be a classical result for Rudin--Keisler isomorphic (summable) ideals of N, but I just didn't figure out how to prove it; that's why I posted it here :) Should I delete completely the question?

Comment: Not sure. See: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29191/should-duplicate-questions-be-deleted   and decide for yourself

Comment: @AdamRubinson Thanks for the link: basically, it states that "we should leave it here iff it is useful to avoid further duplicates". I believe that the title is sufficiently different, even if at first sight we discover it is exactly the same problem. If someone else thinks differently, let me know and I will delete it.

Comment: This will be of interest for a future reader: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.04658.pdf

Comment: I agree that your phrasing of the question is significantly different and more readable than the original question, so I agree, don’t delete it